# How do I write je_malloc_stats_print into a file?

Tags: malloc

How do I write `je_malloc_stats_print()` result into a file instead of `stderr`?
Now what I can do is only je_malloc_stats_print(NULL, NULL, NULL) to stderr;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter is a callback function pointer, and the second is for passing data to the callback.  You can use these parameters to implement writing to a file.  From the [jemalloc manual page](http://www.canonware.com/download/jemalloc/jemalloc-latest/doc/jemalloc.html):

> void malloc_stats_print(
>         void (*write_cb) (void *, const char *) ,
>         void *cbopaque,
>         const char *opts);

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Actually The default function, it uses inside print the stat data on STDERR output stream. To print it to a file, It needs to provide a callback function, which it will call to print the buf stream into. */

int g_fd;

void print_my_jemalloc_data(void *opaque, const char *buf);

int main()

{

  int fd = open("heap_stats.out,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0666);

  g_fd = fd;

  malloc_stats_print(print_my_jemalloc_data,NULL,NULL); 

  /*Passing my callback routine which jemalloc will use internally to print data into*/

return 0;

}

void print_my_jemalloc_data(void *opaque,const char *buf)
{
 write(g_fd,buf,strlen(buf));`enter code here`
}
```

You may replace your function, with same signature, and replace at malloc_stat_print API, first parameter call back function. It will be passed on buf, which you may print in your defined file stream, which you have opened before..